# how do you create a dynamic tabs using jquery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, tabs

i'm new to jquery and I like to know how to do the following:

1) Dynamically create tabs with iFrame inside

2) ability to remove tabs on the fly without postback

3) tabs are unlimited and can shrink depending on the length of the browser

Sorry if this may be too much to ask, but i'd like to learn how to do this. A perfect example of what I'm trying to achieve is the tabs present in the new Yahoo mail UI. When the user selects a mail entry, a new tab will be generated on the fly.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this example..  This creates tabs dynamically the way you probably wanted.

[Dynamically adding jQuery Tabs](http://blog.favrik.com/2009/08/11/dynamically-adding-jquery-tabs-round2/)

Here's a quick working demo..
[Dynamic TAB Demo](http://blog.favrik.com/examples/tabs/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery Tabs 3 Plugin](http://stilbuero.de/jquery/tabs_3/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery Tabs element at http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs

Comment: thank you, but how do i program it to add a new tab without losing state on the other tabs?

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery tabs plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) can be used. You will not lose the state on the other tabs, because they aren't removed, but simply hidden (display: none).